# Am i using ng-route properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku

I have an angular application. The routing features works when i run it locally but when i deploy it to heroku it doesnt work the same. When it was deployed on heroku, it can reach the start page, but after entering credentials to move to the accounts page,it doesnt route. Rest of the js code kicks in fine but i notice that im still on the  /Login url so i know i havent been moved to /Home.I have included the config portion of my app.js file below:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
        .when('/Home', {templateUrl: 'web_pages/home.php'})
        .when('/Vault', {templateUrl: 'web_pages/vault.php'})
        .when('/Tasks', {templateUrl: 'web_pages/tasks.php'})
        .when('/TimeLog', {templateUrl: 'web_pages/time_log.php'})
        .when('/SpendingLog', {templateUrl: 'web_pages/spending_log.php'})
        .when('/AboutApp', {templateUrl: 'web_pages/about_app.php'})
        .when('/Login', {templateUrl: 'web_pages/login.php'})


        .otherwise({redirectTo: "/Login"});});
```

Im asking if im using ng-route properly because when login is successful, i redirect by using the following code:

```
 $location.path('/Home');
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: So i now know that the routing is the feature thats breaking my app on deployment, is there a method for angular routing other then ng-route? Or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<base href="/">` in your index.html

Comment: i will try that, I had used <base href="/index.php">